# Windows 2008 Server R2 Unresponsive when writing to a shared drive

Tags: windows-server-2008

Whenever I try to write to a shared drive on my Win2K8 R2 machine. It writes some of the files to the server. However after a while the machine becomes unresponsive (cannot ping, not remote desktop, ..). All I can do is reboot the system.

In the eventlog i only have 2 events. One being EventId 41 (power lost) and 6008 (unexpected). That's all the information I have (thus none actually).

I have a screen attached to the machine, but when the machine becomes unresponsive the screen remains blank as if there is no computer attached.

Any ideas on how I can gather more information about what is happening? It is really curious that I can only reproduce this by writing data to it over the network (wireless).

Comment: If I follow correctly, you don't have this issue if you write data to it locally ? If thats the case I would try the following 3 steps : disable the wifi card and test it with a wired connection , if that works re enable the card and update the wifi drivers, if that still isnt working replace the wifi card.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the server is of course connected by wire.  The laptop from which I am copying is sending it wireless to a wifi router which sends it tru the wire to the server.

Comment: How much data are you trying to write? Have you tried robocopy? http://serverfault.com/questions/46655/how-do-you-limit-the-bandwidth-for-a-file-copy You could use procmon on the server to see what it does: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Try disabling IPv6 on the server NIC card.

Comment: Disabled IPv6 and was able to copy over 10 gig without any problems.  Currently trying to copy more data, and so far it is looking good.

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Still no luck, copied about 20gig and then failed again.  No error-report or memory dump.

Comment: I agree with Grizly that you should use Procmon to get more information about what is going on. Use this command: "procmon.exe /Quiet /Minimized /BackingFile abc.PML" that way you can look at what happened later on. Be careful where you save that backing file, it can get very large.

Comment: Did you check your disks/controller?  A faulty drive or controller can cause all sorts of weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an older or newer machine? It does sound like a hardware problem, but without a BSOD or some kind of dump, there isnt much to tell. Memory is often times a cheap test item that can easily be replaced to further troubleshoot. I had a small ITX server do the exact same thing with new memory, and replacing the memory did fix my problem. It's a shot in the dark, but at least one step closer.

Comment: The machine is 2 years old.  Memory has just been replaced and diagnostics signal no errors.

The problem is that no memory dump or BSOD is available (maybe it is, but I cannot see anything because my screen goes black after it all happens).  Any ideas how to increase logging that I can actually see what the computer was doing when it became unresponsive (if it is actually still doing something?)