# Bulk file copy while limiting disk utilization?

Tags: backup, windows-7, robocopy, files

I saw that Robocopy can limit network bandwidth in this answer [How do you limit the bandwidth for a file copy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/46655/how-do-you-limit-the-bandwidth-for-a-file-copy)

I have plenty of bandwidth on the LAN, but I don't want to saturate the disk on the system originating the copy (Windows 7).

I vaguely remember reading that Win7 has some facilities for disk prioritization and/or throttling. 
Is there a version of RoboCopy that takes advantage of those OS features?

Or is there a different way to limit the disk impact of a large file copy job?

Comment: Your question is better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

See [this question over at Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7) on the topic of setting I/O priorities for a process. Basically, set the CPU priority of your process to "Idle" to also set the I/O priority to "very low".

There usually is only little value in setting a **bandwidth** limit for limiting disk I/O since disks are capable of delivering a high sustained throughput on contiguous data but would have great difficulties resulting in high latencies and low throughput with random I/O.